# Dynamically create a class name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have some code in PHP file that creates a button and the target of that button is a DIV (findOptionsBox).

The button gets repeated multiple times on the page and so the target of each button should be a unique DIV Id.

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-
 target="#findOptionsBox">
       ......
</button>

<div id="findOptionsBox" class="search-box collapse">
......
<div>
```

So my question is how to make 'findOptionsBox' a variable that can be supplied to the data-target of each myBtn and the same variable can also be the ID of the corresponding div.

I am looking to end up with something like this:

......

```
<div id="findOptionsBox_1" class="search-box collapse">
......
<div>
```

......

```
<div id="findOptionsBox_2" class="search-box collapse">
......
<div>
```

I need the btnIds and the DivIds to be unique and each btnId to refer to the corresponding DivId.

I am looking to do this in Javascript and am trying something like:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var count = 0;

            count++;
    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: So if they are generated in PHP, why are you hooking it up with JavaScript? Why is the PHP code not generating the ids?

Comment: Just give all the buttons and all the divs the same class and then use `.closest` or `.find` in your jquery

Comment: @epascarello Could you please elaborate. I am a novice in PhP and don't know how to get it to generate the Id. I assumed that I would need to use Javascript to do this.

Comment: Well I assume you are outputting the HTML with PHP in a for loop so use the index of the loop and spit out the ids...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/0hx4mLaw/1/

- Create a `div` to contain options box (`#options-container`)
- Clone `#findOptionsBox` and change the `id`
- Insert into `#options-container`

Code:

```
var PREFIX_ID = "findOptionsBox_";

$("#myBtn").click(function(e) {

  $("#options-container").empty();
    var totalOptions = $("#numberOfOptions").val();
    for (var i=0; i<totalOptions; i++) {
    var newBox = $("#findOptionsBox").clone();
    newBox.attr("id", PREFIX_ID + i);
    newBox.appendTo("#options-container");
    newBox.show();
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much !!